# PDO INSERT statement not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Thanks to many people on the community of SO I have been trying to switch everything over to PDO. I have an INSERT INTO statement that I tried converting over to PDO but it is not inserting. I am not getting any errors either.

Here is what I was trying to convert:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("host", "username", "password", "DBname"); 
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO badge_status (username, badge1)
VALUES ('$username', 'finished')");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

PDO version

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');
$username = $_SESSION['jigowatt']['username'];
$awardFinished = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO badge_status (username, badge1) VALUES ('$username', 'finished')');
?>
```

Thanks if you can catch what's going on or can fix this!

Comment: Please , read the manual. You do not even understand ho to concatenate a string.

Comment: If you're using PDO, which is great, you **must** use the [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) feature to properly escape your data. Do not use it in the hazardously unsafe `mysql_query` style.

Comment: I already have, I wouldn't post this if I didn't. The manual is not as helpful as many seem to think.

Comment: The manual has many examples, but there are [tutorials](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) that might be better. Read the section on "Prepared Statements" first.

Comment: @tadman , please do not sent people to NetTutsPlus (the code in that tutorial is injectable). Instead you should direct people to: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: @tereško oh no, thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you prepare your statement with `$awardFinished = $db->prepare(...);`, you have to execute it:

```
$awardFinished->execute();
```

Also, and I'm not sure if this is just an error in your post or your actual code, but you have invalid single-quote usage here:

```
$db->prepare('INSERT INTO badge_status (username, badge1) VALUES ('$username', 'finished')');
```

Regardless of fixing *that*, you're using a prepared statement; you shouldn't be directly inserting your variable into your query.

Try updating to:

```
$awardFinished = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO badge_status (username, badge1) VALUES (:username, "finished")');
$awardFinished->execute(array(':username' => $username));
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I can learn this stuff a lot faster with real tangible code. I will accept this answer when the 10 minute limit has passed. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @AoiHana No problem at all, I'm glad I could help out!

Answer (score 1):

First issue I see is those single quotes in your query, you need to escape them:

`'INSERT INTO badge_status (username, badge1) VALUES (\'$username\', \'finished\')'`

Next you need to `execute` the statement:

`$awardFinished->execute();`

You don't get errors because you need to tell PDO to throw exceptions like this:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    // .. prepare ..
    $awardFinished->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Just saw newfurniturey's answer... spot on